# TypeError: getRouteAtDepth of undefined when testing ReactComponents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am not sure as to why I am getting this error. I assume it is caused by `<RouteHandler />` within my react component. But being new to `reactjs` I have no idea how to fix it.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRouteAtDepth' of undefined
        at RouteHandler.createChildRouteHandler (/Users/bli1/Development/QE/data-trader/data-trader/spec/views/layout.js:23816:39)
        at RouteHandler.render (/Users/bli1/Development/QE/data-trader/data-trader/spec/views/layout.js:23831:27)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (/Users/bli1/Development/QE/data-trader/data-trader/spec/views/layout.js:12006:35)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponent (/Users/bli1/Development/QE/data-trader/data-trader/spec/views/layout.js:12033:15)
        at wrapper [as _renderValidatedComponent] (/Users/bli1/Development/QE/data-trader/data-trader/spec/views/layout.js:3739:22)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (/Users/bli1/Development/QE/data-trader/data-trader/spec/views/layout.js:11454:31)
        at wrapper [as mountComponent] (/Users/bli1/Development/QE/data-trader/data-trader/spec/views/layout.js:3739:22)
        at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (/Users/bli1/Development/QE/data-trader/data-trader/spec/views/layout.js:3814:36)
        at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (/Users/bli1/Development/QE/data-trader/data-trader/spec/views/layout.js:13009:45)
        at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup (/Users/bli1/Development/QE/data-trader/data-trader/spec/views/layout.js:12593:33)
```

layout-test.js:

```
import React from 'react/addons';
import Layout from '../../app/views/layout.js';

const TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

describe('Layout (deep copy)', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        this.component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Layout />);
        this.logoElement = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(this.component, 'main');
    });

    it('test working', function() {
        expect(this.component).to.exist;
    });
});
```

React Component:

```
var Layout = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div id="data-trader">
                <header className="header">
                    <LogoElement />
                    <QuickMenu elements={[]} user={this.props.user} />
                    <MobileTitle />
                    <UserMenu user={this.props.user} />
                </header>
                <div className="container max">
                    <div className="main">
                        <Breadcrumbs path={ this.props.path } pathName={ this.props.pathName } params={ this.props.params } />
                        <RouteHandler path={ this.props.path } query={ this.props.query } params={ this.props.params } user={this.props.user} />
                    </div>
                    <Footer />
                </div>
                <SideMenu user={this.props.user}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


module.exports = Layout;
```